# SQL: How to Work Around NULLs in a Query?

Tags: sql

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following table (my_table):

```
  student_id year school_major
1        123 2010         arts
2        123 2011         arts
3        123 2012      science
4        222 2020      science
5        222 2021         NULL
6        222 2022         arts
```

**My Question:** I am trying to track the number of times each student changed their major in university:

Here is my SQL code:

```
select sequence, count(*) as count
from(
select student_id,
school_major  || ' , '|| lead(school_major) over (partition by student_id order by student_id) as sequence
from my_table)q
group by sequence;

        sequence count
1           <NA>     2
2    NULL , arts     1
3    arts , arts     1
4 arts , science     1
5 science , NULL     1
```

**My Problem:** This code in not able to properly handle NULL values (e.g. if a student is missing a value). I would like the code to also track transitions between NULL to ARTS, NULL to SCIENCE, etc.

I tried to address this problem by replacing all NULLS with some NON-NULL value (e.g. the word "MISSING") - and then running the query:

```
with my_cte as (select student_id, year, case when school_major is NULL then 'MISSING' else school_major end as school_major from my_table)
    
        select sequence, count(*) as count
        from(
        select student_id,
        school_major || ' , '|| lead(school_major) over (partition by student_id order by student_id) as sequence
        from my_cte)q
        group by sequence;
```

But NULL's are still appearing in the final result:

```
        sequence count
1           <NA>     2
2    NULL , arts     1
3    arts , arts     1
4 arts , science     1
5 science , NULL     1
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems correct sql to me! Can you please show the current output and expected output?

Comment: I can't explain why you are still getting nulls. The query you are showing should not be able to produce nulls. To play save, name the alias different from the column. And you can replace the `CASE` expression with `COALESCE`. E.g. `with my_cte as (select student_id, year, coalesce(school_major, 'MISSING') as smajor from my_table) ...`.

Comment: lead(..) gets ``null`` for last row of partition. Then 'tex'||null - is null also. You can use ``lead(school_major,1,'This is last')``.

Comment: @ ValNik: thank you so much for your reply! If you have time, can you please write an answer with this logic?

Comment: @ Thorsten Kettner: thank you for your reply! if you have time, can you please write an answer with this logic? thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

UPD2:
Try this

```
with my_cte as (
  select student_id, year
    ,case when school_major is NULL then 'MISSING' else school_major end as school_major 
    ,coalesce(lead(school_major,1,'last row') 
           over (partition by student_id order by year),'MISSING') next_major
  from my_table
  )
,changes as(
  select student_id,school_major,next_major,year,next_year
      ,case when next_major<>'last row' then school_major || ' -> '|| next_major
       else '<NA>'
       end as major_sequence
  from my_cte
)
select major_sequence as sequence, count(*) as count
from changes
group by major_sequence;
```

| sequence | count |
| --- | --- |
| arts - arts | 1 |
| MISSING - arts | 1 |
| arts - science | 1 |
| science - MISSING | 1 |
| NA | 2 |

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/bhtOU4_J)

I will propose a solution based on how I understood the question. There is a task for counting the number of changes in the data series.
Pay attention to difference from your query example.

1. `order by year`
2. `group by student_id`

For clarity, solution divided to CTE.

```
-- test data
create table my_table (id int,student_id int, year int,school_major varchar(20));
insert into my_table values
 (1,        123, 2010,'arts')
,(2,        123, 2011,'arts')
,(3,        123, 2012,'science')
,(4,        222, 2020,'science')
,(5,        222, 2021,NULL)
,(6,        222, 2022,'arts')
;
```

1. cte `my_cte` -  substitute nulls in table. It's not necessary, but it's clearer and more convenient.
2. seq -  sequences for school_major. Take current and next.
3. changes - select rows, where current and next school_major differs.
4. grouping by student_id - count changes for student_id

```
with my_cte as (
  select student_id, year
    ,case when school_major is NULL then 'MISSING' else school_major end as school_major 
  from my_table
  )
,seq as (
    select * 
      ,lead(school_major,1,'last row') 
           over (partition by student_id order by year) next_major
       -- only for dev.purpose
      ,lead(year) 
           over (partition by student_id order by year) next_year
      ,school_major || ' -> '|| lead(school_major,1,'last row') 
           over (partition by student_id order by year) as major_sequence
      ,cast(year as varchar) || ' -> '|| lead(cast(year as varchar),1,'last row') 
           over (partition by student_id order by year) as year_sequence
    from my_cte
   )
,changes as(
  select student_id
     ,school_major,next_major,year,next_year,major_sequence,year_sequence 
  from seq
  where school_major<>next_major and next_major<>'last row'
)
select student_id, count(*) as count
  ,string_agg(major_sequence,' , ') sequences
from changes
group by student_id;
```

| student_id | school_major | next_major | year | next_year | major_sequence | year_sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | arts | science | 2011 | 2012 | arts - science | 2011 - 2012 |
| 222 | science | MISSING | 2020 | 2021 | science - MISSING | 2020 - 2021 |
| 222 | MISSING | arts | 2021 | 2022 | MISSING - arts | 2021 - 2022 |

Result (draft)

| student_id | count | sequences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | arts - science |
| 222 | 2 | science - MISSING , MISSING - arts |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HxKnmqvx)

Shorted:

```
with my_cte as (
  select student_id, year
    ,case when school_major is NULL then 'MISSING' else school_major end as school_major 
    ,coalesce(lead(school_major,1,'last row') 
           over (partition by student_id order by year),'MISSING') next_major
  from my_table
  )
select student_id, count(*) as count
from my_cte
where school_major<>next_major and next_major<>'last row'
group by student_id;
```